# Anyone remember and old C library called TCXL?

Tags: c

Back in the early 1990's, I used a library of routines in C called TCXL. I just wonder what ever happened to the guys who made that. I was about 25 years old the time, and learned C from a manual I printed out on my dot matrix printer. I think was using Turbo C, and I guess I downloaded TCXL from some bulletin board, or maybe Compuserve?

That library had cool routines to create "windows" for pop-ups and to create regions on the screen, as well has many other cool things that I can't fully recall. All this was in DOS of course.

Comment: What's the question? What happened to those guys? I think this is the wrong forum... wikipedia maybe?

Answer (score 2):

http://cd.textfiles.com/swheaven1/UTILITY/

Answer (score 1):

Mike Smedley, CXL's original author:
http://www.mikesmedley.com/